# BS4: extracting text from div elements

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract part of the class name and two tag elements from a div element (input at the end of this post).

This code

```
     divs = soup.find_all("div", class_="tab_box")
     for div in divs:
         print(div)
```

gets me

```
    <div class="tab_box stat_alarm"><span>pH [pH]</span><h1>6.9</h1></div>
    <div class="tab_box stat_alarm"><span>Redox [mV]</span><h1>667</h1></div>
    <div class="tab_box stat_ok"><span>Temp. [°C]</span><h1>9.5</h1></div>
    <div class="tab_box"></div>
```

Adding

```
print(div.text)
```

yields:

```
pH [pH]6.9
Redox [mV]667
Temp. [°C]9.5
```

However, what I would like is three elements per div. Like:

stat_alarm, pH [pH], 6.9

stat_ok, Temp., 9.5

How can I get there?

Answer (score 1):

You can do for example:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_text = """\
    <div class="tab_box stat_alarm"><span>pH [pH]</span><h1>6.9</h1></div>
    <div class="tab_box stat_alarm"><span>Redox [mV]</span><h1>667</h1></div>
    <div class="tab_box stat_ok"><span>Temp. [°C]</span><h1>9.5</h1></div>
    <div class="tab_box"></div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")


for div in soup.select("div.stat_alarm, div.stat_ok"):
    a, b, c = (div.attrs["class"][-1], *div.stripped_strings)
    print(f"{a:<15} {b:<15} {c:<15}")
```

Prints:

```
stat_alarm      pH [pH]         6.9            
stat_alarm      Redox [mV]      667            
stat_ok         Temp. [°C]      9.5
```

Comment: Excellent, Thanks!